# How to open each datepicker in table? [Mui lib]

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm having a problem that is:
I use the table of the Mui library. Each row contains an datepicker. I'm required that when TextField is pressed, Datepicker will be displayed. I use State for opening condition but when I press it all open.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIxpf.png)
In addition, when choosing a date, there will be state set to show on TextField.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEfcM.png)
How to know that which datepicker is click

Comment: Please update you question to include relevant code in a code snippet.  You can also link to a codesandox for a practical demonstration, but some lines of code in the question should be done as well.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.